# writing and saving a file in android application

Tags: android, file, filewriter

m trying to write a file when a button `Save_btn` is pressed however, when i run the application it runs smoothly with no errors but the file is nowhere to be found.

I am trying to write to the internal storage of the device. the text being written is in a edittext field. i would like this text from the EditText to be written to the file

I have included the code I'm using below;

```
Save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.g);
    Save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View views) {
                                        TextView CodeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Code_Viewer);
                                        CodeView.setText(CodeView.getText());
                                        try {
                                            String etName = CodeView.getText().toString();
                                            if (!etName.trim().equals("")) {
                                                File file = new File("/Documents/test.txt");

                                                //if file doesnt exists, then create it
                                                if (!file.exists()) {
                                                    file.createNewFile();
                                                }


                                                FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(), true);
                                                BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
                                                bufferWritter.write(etName);
                                                bufferWritter.close();
                                            }
                                        } catch (IOException e) {

                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
    );
```

Any advice on how to get the file to write properly would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly, where do you want to save your file? what are you trying to achieve? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I am trying to write to the internal storage of the device. the text being written is in a edittext field. i would like this text from the EditText to be written to the file

Comment: No.  `File file = new File("/Documents/test.txt");`. That is an impossible path. Put a  `Toast()` in that catch block which displays `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: `if (!file.exists()) {
                                                    file.createNewFile();
                                                }`. Remove hat code. It is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this code with yours :

```
    Save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.g);
    Save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View views) {
                TextView CodeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Code_Viewer);
                CodeView.setText(CodeView.getText());
                String etName = CodeView.getText().toString();

                File dir = new File(getFilesDir(), "yourfolder");
                if(!dir.exists())
                {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                String textFileName="textFile.txt";
                File file = new File(dir.getPath(), textFileName );
                if(file.exists())
                {
                    file.delete();
                }
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(etName);
                    bw.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    );
```

you should note these points :

- this code will create file on /data/data/[your app package name]/files/[your folder]/[your textFileName]
- it always remove your file if the file name was the same , so you should get unique name for each one.(you can include date and time in file name)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still cant see the directory for the app

Comment: you use physical phone or emulator ?

Comment: Physical phone Huawei P9

Comment: I have it isn't there the package name isn't a directory

Comment: put this  ** Log.i("FilePath" , file.getPath()); ** after **  File file = new File(dir.getPath(), textFileName ); **  and check your logcat with info filter , it should show you where the file is saved...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can work because the file path you're specifying is a) absolute and b) pointing to a directory you probably have no write permission for.

```
File file = new File("/Documents/test.txt");
```

This references the `Documents` folder in the file systems root directory instead of your apps files.

If you want to save it locally for use in your own application, you can try [Context#getFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()), e.g.

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDirectory(), "yourfile.txt");
```

In case you want to save it somewhere other applications can use it you might need a more sophisticated approach, e.g. a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: When trying this it give the error "can not resolve symbol context"?

Comment: Do it without context. Its implicit.

Comment: Your activity is a context (so is your app) and your fragment has a method getContext(). Try `final Context context = this;` before the click handler if this happens in an activity. Or use greenapps method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "test.txt");`

instead of

`File file = new File("/Documents/test.txt");`

to save to your internal storage. The rest of your code can stay the same.